# Hide one DIV if another DIV exists on page

Tags: jquery, html, hidden

I have a search page with one div on it (#A), when I do a search, I have made another div appear on the page (#B), however I don't ever want the two divs on the page at the same time.

How can I code it so that if #B exists, #A is hidden? Do I use the jQuery .length attribute??

Comment: Can you post the code you've got so far in a jsfiddle?

Comment: If they're both on the same level in the DOM you should be able to use something like `#B ~ #A {display:none;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `length`:

```
//if B exist...
if($('#B').length){
   $('#A').hide();
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/4P9Hq/

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to check the css state of the div, ie, whether it is display:none or display:block

```
var aVisible = $('#divA').css('display');
if (aVisible == 'block') {
//Put your code here to hide DivA
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `toggle()` an element by passing a `bool` into it as an argument. This combined with checking if the element is `:hidden` would work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkncz/)

```
$('#A').toggle($('#B').is(':hidden'));
```

**OR** checking the existence with `length`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez3NH/)

```
$('#A').toggle(!$('#B').length);
```